# Running app: No such file or directory

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod

I'm making a android app for the first time. I have created an project in the Android studio. And I want it to run. But when I click on the run button I get this error:

```
Uploading file
local path: /Users/meeh/Downloads/phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/bin/ChatAlot/out/production/ChatAlot/ChatAlot.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.glemma.chatalot
Adb Transfer Protocol Error.
No such file or directory
```

I couldn't get a fix through googling it so maybe you guys know something about it

I'm using an old HTC desire with cyanogenmod

Comment: Do you enable debugging mode on phone?

Comment: Yes i turned it on :)

Comment: Could you push your application by command:
adb push /Users/meeh/Downloads/phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/bin/ChatAlot/out/production/ChatAlot/ChatAlot.apk /sdcard/
if no you have probably problem with drivers

Answer (score 1):

If it's on emulator, **assuming your android SDK is located at `/usr/local/android-studio/sdk`,**

Fire following command to open up your **AVD Manager**

```
$ /usr/local/android-studio/sdk/tools/android avd
```

And then edit your AVD's **SD card size**.

[image: SD card size]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue (API 16, 17 amd 18) until I added 200 Mib to the SD card option. Below is a screen shot of the settings that got me past this issue.

If its relevant I was running this on a 64 bit Windows 7 PC and using Android Studio.

[image: AVD Setup for Galaxy Nexus]

Answer (score 0):

I get this annoying error on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Android Studio. I tried it all. On official Google web there is no solution about this problem. I found a workaround (something I never done before) - connecting tablet and running emulator on it. It starts faster than its emulator on Eclipse ever did.

Comment: You appear to be describing testing on a device rather than an emulator, but that is what the asker is already trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

change applicationId in defaultConfig of build.gradle file